# How to do an svnadmin task with VisualSVN?

Tags: visualsvn-server, svn

We need to dump the content of a repository using svnadmin dump, but we are using svnadmin in Windows and we don't find the svnadmin command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the "svnadmin.exe" binary in %ProgramFiles%\VisualSVN\bin by default. The current version of VisualSVN comes pre-packaged with the Subversion 1.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

look where SVN installed, depends on distro might be in different location, but you should have svnadmin binary there (svnadmin.exe) that what you need to use in order to do svnadmin dump

i guess the other thing you could try is to install subversion and use svnadmin from known location